# Sum of elements in basis form a basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $v_1,...,v_n$ is a basis of $V.$ Prove that
$$v_1+v_2, v_2+v_3, ...,v_{n-1}+v_n, v_n$$
is also a basis.

I started by showing that $v_1+v_2, v_2+v_3, ...,v_{n-1}+v_n, v_n$ is linearly independent, but I wasn't sure how to proceed after that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: this is not true. $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ is the standard canonical basis for $\mathbb {R}^3$, but $((1,1,0),(0,1,1))$ spans only a plane in $\mathbb {R}^3$. Do you mean a basis of a subspace?

Comment: Have you left you $v_n + v_1$ from the new set ? . Most likely that is the case.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, I fixed the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just prooved that the set $\{ v_1 + v_2, v_2 + v_3, ..., v_{n-1} + v_n, v_n \}$ is linearly independent.

Next thing you should remember from vector spaces basis is that if $B_1$ and $B_2$ are basis of vector space $V$ then $ |B_1| = |B_2| = dim(V)$.

So, if your set $\{ v_1 + v_2, v_2 + v_3, ..., v_{n-1} + v_n, v_n \}$ (let's call it $B'$) is linearly independent and the number of elements in that set is the same number of elements you have in $\{ v_1, v_2, ..., v_n \}$ (ie, the dimension of your vector space), then $B'$ must be a basis.

Comment: But in this case $|B^{'}| = n - 1$

Comment: Note that the OP just changed the question. Please edit your answer appropriately, especially since it did not properly answer the first question.

Comment: You're right, @echzhen, I forgot the final term ($v_n$) of the set, so the set would be: $B' = \{ v_1 + v_2, v_2 + v_3, ..., v_{n-1} + v_n, v_n \}$.

Answer (score 1):

A direct approach to showing span.

Let $v = c_1 v_1 + \cdots + c_n v_n$

Goal: show that 
$$ v = d_1 (v_1 + v_2) + \cdots + d_{n-1} (v_{n-1} + v_n) + d_n v_n$$
$$ =  d_1 v_1 + (d_1 + d_2) v_2 + \cdots + (d_{n-1} + d_{n})v_n $$

This tells you what to choose for the $d_i$. Namely, recursively define it to be: $d_1 = c_1$ and then $d_{k+1} = c_{k+1} - d_k$

Comment: Good proofs contain explanations of what is going on, in my opinion. I think this answer can be improved a lot.